# Port forwarding

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

how to configure local ports to allow connections from other hosts in LAN, in order to reach a web application through my ssh tunnel ?

I have something like this:

```
ssh -L1000:localhost:80 10.10.10.1
```

Other hosts must be able to use: http://my_ip_address:1000 to reach 10.10.10.1:80

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your public IP in the connection line, so the other hosts can connect to this connection. Also specifying the `-g` switch will allow others to connect to your forwarded port. If you use `localhost` as in your example, only you can connect:

```
ssh -g -L1000:my_ip_address:80 10.10.10.1
```

You also might need to check you firewall configuration.

Comment: I've been trying, it's not working. I need to NAT the my_ip_addres into localhost to make it work but I don't know how do that on linux.

Comment: That's how I solved:

ssh -g -L 1000:localhost:80